# Two serial connections to the raspberry pi makes it to slow to handle the data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I try to build a music device kinda like a drum with led lights, because of some particular hardware and software requirements I ended up with a Raspberry pi, a MakeyMakey and a Arduino to control the sound, the (captive) touch and the led lighting. The overall picture of these devices look like
this:

[image]

Here you can see two devices transferring data to the Raspberry pi the MakeyMakey and the Arduino. At the current moment I use a serial connections to send the data between these devices, but the reading speed is not being able to catch up with the speed the data get send even tough I tried changing the ReadLine function to the function proposed [here](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/216#issuecomment-369414522). Disconnect one device and it will work. Mabey there are better ways to communicate data I am unaware of, or is my my code just awefull and can it be improven. What should I do to make the Raspberry pi be able to handle this data?

The simplified code of the three devices

Raspberry pi:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env/ python3
    import serial
    import serial.tools.list_ports
    import time
    import array

    # Class to read serial(Faster than that of the library)
    class ReadLine:
        def __init__(self, s):
            self.buf = bytearray()
            self.s = s

        def readline(self, time):
            i = self.buf.find(b"\n")
            if i >= 0:
                r = self.buf[:i+1]
                self.buf = self.buf[i+1:]
                return r
            # I changed this because the breakline can take some time to occur
            start = time.perf_counter()
            while (time.perf_counter() - start) <= time:
               i = max(1, min(2048, self.s.in_waiting))
               data = self.s.read(i)
               i = data.find(b"\n")
               if i >= 0:
                   r = self.buf + data[:i+1]
                   self.buf[0:] = data[i+1:]
                   return r
               else:
                   self.buf.extend(data)
            return b"No data \n"

    def main():
       # initializes arduino and makeymakey
       arduino = 0
       makeymakey = 0
       ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
       for p in ports:
           print(p)
           if "Arduino" in p:
               arduino = serial.Serial(p.device, 9600, timeout=0.1)
           elif "SparkFun MaKey MaKey" in p:
               makeymakey = serial.Serial(p.device, 9600, timeout=0.1)

       if arduino == 0:
            print("Arduino not found")
            exit(1)
       elif makeymakey == 0:
            print("MakeyMakey not found")
            exit(1)

       # Flush input buffer
       arduino.flush()
       makeymakey.flush()

       # Initializes readline
       rl_arduino = ReadLine(arduino)
       rl_makeymakey = ReadLine(makeymakey)

       # Start values
       key_pressed = array.array("f", [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
       last_update = time.perf_counter()
        
       while True:
            # Reads values of arduino and sets volume based on this
            bytes = rl_arduino.readline(0.00001).rstrip().decode()
            # Set volume

            # Reads makeymakey and creates sound + updates key pressed
            bytes = rl_makeymakey.readline(0.01).rstrip().decode()
            # This also gets repeated for other key values
            if bytes == "p97":
                # Play sound
                key_pressed[0] = 1

            if (time.perf_counter() - last_update) >= 0.1:
                # Sends for every key pressed the led_nummer that is pressed
                last_update = time.perf_counter()
                for led_nummer in range(8):
                    if key_pressed[led_nummer] == 1:
                        arduino.write(str(led_nummer).encode('utf-8'))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

Arduino:

```c
    void setup() {
       Serial.begin(9600);
       timer = millis();
    }

    void loop() {
       // Checkes if the serial has a value and if so changes the color change based on that value
       if (Serial.available() > 0) {
          int ledNumber = Serial.read() - '0';
          // Some led stuff
       }

       //
       // Some led stuff
       //

       // Reads the potentiometer and knob and writes this to the serial
       if ((millis() - timer) >= 400){
          potentio = analogRead(A1);
          val = map(potentio, 0, 1024, 0, 10);
          Serial.println(val);
          if(digitalRead(10) == HIGH){
             Serial.println("Pressed");
          }else{
             Serial.println("Released");
          }
          timer = millis();
        }
        delay(50);
    }
```

MakeyMakey:

```c
    void setup(){
       Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() { 
       delay(100);
       if (pressed && unpressed_was_last_state) {
          Serial.print("p");
          Serial.println(keys[i]);
       }else if(unpressed && pressed_was_last_state){
          Serial.print("r");
          Serial.println(keys[i]);
       }

       //
       // Some logic
       //

    }
```

Comment: This question is really too broad: you've effectively dumped all your code here and asked, "what's wrong with it?" Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some thoughts on reducing the scope of this question to something we can help with.

Comment: Your code to too long for a Sunday morning, but I was wondering (1) if you are using the non blocking mode of python serial commands. (2) speed up 9600bd to much much higher bauds.

Comment: Raspberry Pis have 4 CPU cores. You are using just one. I don't know what's controlling what or how everything is interrelated in your application, but you could likely use several threads, one reading each serial stream and then passing messages via a multithreading Queue to a main program so it doesn't block reading one device and thereby ignore another.